# How to center large font text and let small font text align bottom

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, font-size

I want to have two text blocks on the same row, where the text with larger font is vertically aligned middle and the text with smaller font has the same text baseline as the one with larger font.
Look at my fiddle where the large text is centered as desired. The smaller text though is also centered, but I want it to be a bit lower so that it feels like the two text blocks are on the same "line".
https://jsfiddle.net/phzzhevq/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="my-table">  
    <div class="my-cell">
        <span class="large-text">Large text</span>
    </div> 
    <div class="my-cell">
        <span class="small-text">Small text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-table {
    display: table;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: red;
}

.my-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.large-text {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.small-text {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Image that explains the desired result:
[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this little fix. Please let me know if this is what you wanted.

```
.my-table {
  display: table;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
}

.my-cell {
  display: table-cell;
}

.large-text {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height:80px;
}

.small-text {
  font-size: 20px;
   line-height:80px;
}
```

Comment: It works! Just one small problem left. The "my-table" becomes larger than 80px. Is it possible to make it have exactly 80px height

Comment: Instead of using `display: table` in  **.my-table** use `display:inline-block`. and use `display:inline-block` in **.my-cell** as well.

Comment: Can't get it to vertical align by using inline-block. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/phzzhevq/6/

Comment: Hi Mike, what do you mean by vertical align in this context?? Can you be more specific.

Comment: I mean that the "padding" below and above the text should be the same. 
Compare jsfiddle.net/phzzhevq/6 and https://jsfiddle.net/phzzhevq/7/. The former (with inline-block) has more padding above the text than below which is not desired.

Comment: That is because of the font difference between two texts. I think changing the line height of Large text to desired value might help. Try reducing the line height of large text, that will give you the desired view.

Comment: The difference between the fonts is the reason for the original question. I can't get it to work by reducing the line-height so I have to mark the question as unanswered

Comment: Can you just share a screenshot of what exactly you need. Because I think my first solution did worked well. If you could just share the requirement as a screenshot, I might find another way to do this.

Comment: I've uploaded an image with the desired result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142090/discussion-between-sreenathpg-and-mike).

Comment: Works with change according to comment

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it following way.

```css
.my-table {
  display: table;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
}

.my-cell {
  display: table-cell;
}

.large-text {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height:80px;
}

.small-text {
  font-size: 20px;
   line-height:80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-table">  
    <div class="my-cell">
        <span class="large-text">Large text</span>
    </div> 
    <div class="my-cell">
        <span class="small-text">Small text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some other options (i used flex for vertical alignment)

`line-height: 0.8` and `font-variant: small-caps`

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/1en2rsua/1/

or without `small-caps`

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/1en2rsua/2/

or `margin-bottom: -4px`

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/1en2rsua/3/

Comment: Cannot use this due to browser support